# Div related error on basic html

Tags: html, css

I've been having issues with this line of html I keep getting errors and cannot find the source, the error highlight is on the end of the last div, but when i remove it there's an error on the end of the body tag. https://jsfiddle.net/LfxLhcap/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Flower Shop</title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
    <img src="images/red_rose.jpg" alt="red rose banner"/>
</header>


<nav>
    <ul class="navlist">
    <ul>
<li class="our staff"></li><a href="our_staff.html">our staff</a>

<li class="our product"></li><a href="our_product.html">our product</a>

<li class="our mesage"></li><a href="our_message.html">our message</a>
    </ul>

<div class="image">

<img src="images/woman_smiling.jpg" alt="women smilling">

</div>

<div class="content">
    <h1>Welcome to Flowershop.com</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.     Suspendisse nec dolor ipsum. Fusce in nunc lorem, dictum eleifend augue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris eu lectus id nisi adipiscing eleifend vitae a nisi.</p>
</div>

<div class="right_column">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec dolor ipsum. Fusce in nunc lorem, dictum eleifend augue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris eu lectus id nisi adipiscing eleifend vitae a nisi.</p>
</div>


        </div>


<footer></footer>


</body>
</html>
```

also tips on aligning the two paragraphs to the right of `women_smiling` in css would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please create a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: What type of error message are you seeing, and where does the error message come from (HTML validator, HTML editor??)

Comment: I've been using brackets and the last div have been highlighted as an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your html:

- You have two start tags for `<ul>`, but only one end tag (`</ul>`).
- You have a start tag for `<nav>` but no end tag.

Another issue is that your `<li>` elements do not contain the `<a>` elements:

```
<li class="our staff"></li><a href="our_staff.html">our staff</a>
```

should be:

```
<li class="our staff"><a href="our_staff.html">our staff</a></li>
```

You should ask a separate question regarding alignment (after searching of course - it's bound to already be asked).

Comment: Also, `our staff` can never be a class name. `our_staff` maybe.

Comment: @Raptor yeah, good point. `our staff` is actually two classes - probably not what OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing close tags for nav tag and the ul tag with navlist class.